# Python 2.7 unittest using assertAlmostEqual is not functioning properly

Tags: python, python-unittest

My python version is 2.7.13.

I need to test using the `unittest` module, and the data type I am testing with are floats. In the docs it says to use `assertAlmostEqual` for the small discrepancy when comparing floats for equality.

This is what I did:

`self.assertAlmostEqual(41.7777777777776, 41.777, places=3)`

I run the above code and it yields a failed test result, like the following:

`self.assertAlmostEqual(41.7777777777776, 41.777, places=3)
AssertionError: 41.7777777777776 != 41.777 within 3 places`

What I am doing wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: To three places, `41.7777777777776` is `41.778`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers are not equal to 3 decimal places, [as defined by `assertAlmostEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual):

> Test that first and second are approximately (or not approximately) equal by computing the difference, rounding to the given number of decimal places (default 7), and comparing to zero.

The difference between your numbers, rounded to 3 decimal places, is `0.001`.

Comment: So if would want to make that test pass I would have to write `assertAlmostEqual(41.77777777776, 41.777, 2)` am I correct?

Comment: @MosheRabaev: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual):

> Test that first and second are approximately (or not approximately) equal by computing the difference, rounding to the given number of decimal places (default 7), and comparing to zero. Note that these methods round the values to the given number of decimal places (i.e. like the round() function) and not significant digits.

In your case, `round(41.7777777777776 - 41.777, 3) != 0.0`.

Comment: It's taking the difference and then rounding, not rounding and then comparing.